# What is the meaning of God's omni-powers?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god, omniscience, omnipotence, omnibenevolence

It is a common understanding among Christians I know that God has these four attributes:

- Omnipresence
- Omniscience
- Omnipotence
- Omnibenevolence

A grammatical interpretation would explain them as unlimited or maybe absolute, but I'm interested in the biblical approach to this matter. What is the meaning attributed to each of these "powers" in the Bible?

Comment: God is everywhere (and everywhen), God knows everything, God is all powerful, and God is source of everything good.

Comment: That's gonna be a tough noodle. Other than omnipotent (all-powerful, pantokratos) I'm having some difficulty recalling where those would come from vis a vis the Bible.

Comment: Hi there! If you check out this article (http://www.herealittletherealittle.net/index.cfm?page_name=Mystery ), you'll see that it has some verses for some of the attributes you mentioned. Thanks and I hope this was useful.

Comment: @user1539 Can you make it an answer?

Comment: Here's a puzzler: Hebrews 6:18 states God cannot lie (although he could be said to be a bit deceptive in a few places). If he cannot lie - is he omnipotent?

Comment: @MarcGravell If God lied, then he would not be omnibenevolent. That's like saying could God make hot sauce so hot even he could not use it? It's a contradicting statement.

Comment: @Shredder yes, "omni" suffers many of the same comparison/contradiction issue as "infinity" does in math. It is indeed a contradicting statement, but it isn't my premise...

Comment: @MarcGravell IMO a contradicting premise is not valid for marking something as fallible.

Comment: @Renan Thanks, but the article is well-written to the point that I can't add one iota of value by writing my own input.

Comment: @MarcGravell Omni-, as with *infinite*, is not intended to include members that don't belong to the set. E.g., the set of all integers is infinite, but only includes integers. And, just as we can't pick a non-integer like 3.1 or "cat" and expect to find it in the infinite set, we can't pick powers that don't exist an expect them to be in the set of "all powers."

Comment: @svidgen after a year, you'll excuse me if this is hazy... But: if we're taking about the power to lie - that is definitely a power that exists. If, however, you are re-defining omnipotence as "the set of powers that the owner has", than that's awesome: I'm omnipotent too! I have all the powers that I have!

Comment: @MarcGravell You're oversimplifying, I think. *To lie* in itself doesn't mean anything. It's only a rational concept in relation to person P where *P can knowingly reveals a false thought*. God does not possess false thoughts, God *is* Truth. So, it is nonsensical to conceive of God lying. **But, more importantly**, lying is ***a** power*, not **power**: the ability to **do limitlessly**. That is, God has an eternal ability to *do* without time-space limits; contrasted with human power, which is time and space limited: We can be doing one thing at a time in one tiny space.

Comment: @MarcGravell And you might say, *Well then, God is not omnipotent because God cannot think false thoughts!* And, I might be inclined to agree. God "can't" think false thoughts. But again, the more important point is that **pontency** doesn't really refer **a** power, particularly in the weird sense we think of it, but rather *power itself*.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure there are other references, but for example:

Omnipresence: Psalm 139:7-12 describes God being everywhere.

Omnipotence: I can't think of a Bible verse that says, "God is omnipotent". But Deut 4:37 (and many similar verses) talk about God's "might power". Gen 17:1 and others refer to God as "Almighty". Job 11:7b "Can you find out the limits of the Almighty?"

Omnibenevolence: Luke 18:19 "So Jesus said to him, 'Why do you call Me good? No one is good but One, that is, God.'"

I can't think of a verse for omniscience off the top of my head.

Omniscience: OT reference Psalm 69:5 - if He knows all our sins, He knows it all
and NT reference 1st John 3:20 comes right out and says that "...God is greater than our heart, and knows all things."

Comment: [Psalm 139:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm+139:2&version=NIV) looks like a good one. [Here's how I found it.](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=know+thoughts&qs_version=NIV)

Comment: "Almighty" sounds a lot like "Omnipotent" to me.

Answer (score 1):

A google search looking for a meaning/definition of the `omni` prefix will give you a bunch of references that saying it denotes an "all-" meaning. The suffix words can be defined as:

[Potency](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/potency?s=t&ld=1030): power; authority. - [Luke 1:37](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%201:37&version=AMP)
[Presence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/presence?s=t&ld=1030): the state or fact of being present, as with others or in a place. - [Psalm 139:7-12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20139:7-12&version=AMP)
[Science](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/science): the state of knowing. - [Job 37:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2037:16&version=NIV), [Psalm 147:5](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20147:5&version=NIV), [1 John 3:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%203:19-20&version=NIV)
[Benevolent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/benevolent): Characterized by or suggestive of doing good. - [Matt 19:17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2019:17&version=AMP)

As those verses describe, God is all-powerful and all-authoritative, all-present (God's presence is in all places at once), all-knowing, and is all(perfectly)-good.

Comment: The biblical references are precisely what I'm after.

Comment: @Renan Okay, well I was going to add them to Jay's answer, but I'll just put them in mine. See my edit.

Comment: That's a lot better, thank you. I like how you linked everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few verses to add to what has been said.

Omnipresence:

```
 "He is before all things, and in him all things hold together"
 Colossians 1:17
 "For in him we live and move and have our being." 
 Acts 17:28
 "Very truly I tell you," Jesus answered, "before Abraham was born, I am!"
 John 8:58
 "But who is able to build a temple for him,
 since the heavens, even the highest heavens,
 cannot contain him? ...
2 Chronicles 2:6
"I am the Alpha and the Omega,
 the first and the last,
 the beginning and the end." 
 Revelation 21:13
```

These verses show among other things God is not just everywhere(he has to be everywere if the Heavens of Heaven cannot contain Him, also elsewere The whole earth is filled with His glory). It shows He is everytime as well "Before Abraham was I AM" in the context was demonstrating that Jesus is God, but also denoting that He is in a state of presently exsisting (I am) in the past (before Abraham was). And also I AM the Alpha and the Omega, not I Was the alpha and will be the Omega. Not I was the first and will be the last.

Omnipotence:
    “With man this is impossible, but with God all things are possible.” 
    Mathew 19:26
    "I can do all things through Christ who strengthens me."
    Philippians 4:13
It's pretty clear, is anything left out when He said All things? No.

Omniscence:
"Do you not know? Have you not heard? The LORD is the everlasting God, the Creator of the ends of the earth. He will not grow tired or weary, and his understanding no one can fathom" (Isaiah 40:28)

"Nothing in all creation is hidden from God's sight. Everything is uncovered and laid bare before the eyes of him to whom we must give account."
Hebrews 4:13

Apart from the other scriptures that talk about His knowledge and Wisdom, if we had none of them we could infer from his attributes of being everywhere at every time and being all powerful that He would have to know everything since He created all things and all things are in Him.

Omnibenovolence:

```
  "Greater love has no one than this, that one lay down his life for his friends."
John 15:13
"For God so Loved the world, that He gave His only begotten son, that whosoever believes in Him, shall not parish but have everlasting life."
John 3:16
"He that loves not knows not God; for God is love."
1 John 4:8
"Neither is worshiped with men's hands, as though he needed anything,
 seeing he gives to all life, and breath, and all things;"
 Acts 17:25
```

God is not just all loving He is Love itself.